# proto file for multiple inheritance

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

This is the way my classes are modelled. sorry it's long:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class RequestSection
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public List<BaseA> Allrequests;

    public RequestSection()
    {
        Allrequests = new List<BaseA>();
    }
}
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(BaseA<derResponse1>))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(BaseA<derResponse2>))]
public abstract class BaseA
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int baseA = 10;
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(der1))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(der2))]
public abstract class BaseA<T> : BaseA where T : ResponseBaseA, new()
{
    T _Response;
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public new T Response
    {
        get { return _Response; }
        set { _Response = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class der1 : BaseA<derResponse1>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int derive1 = 20;
}
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class der2 : BaseA<derResponse2>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int derive2 = 30;
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(derResponse1))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(derResponse2))]
public abstract class ResponseBaseA
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int responseBaseA = 100;
}
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class derResponse1 : ResponseBaseA
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int derResp1 = 200;
}
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class derResponse2 : ResponseBaseA
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int derResp2 = 300;
}
```

}

the way we create them is here

```
RequestSection section = new RequestSection();
der1 der1 = new der1();
der2 der2 = new der2();

section.Allrequests.Add(der1);
section.Allrequests.Add(der2);
```

Iam not able to serialize section using protobuf-net(both v1 and v2 - they say unknown subtype) so im trying runtime model.

Here is the proto file iam using.

```
message RequestSection{
    repeated BaseA requests=1;
}
message BaseA{
    optional int32 baseA=1;
    optional BaseA1Generic BaseA1Generic =2;
    optional BaseA2Generic BaseA2Generic =3;
}
message BaseA1Generic{
    optional ResponseBaseA baseResponse =1; 
    optional Der1 requestDer1 = 2;
}
message BaseA2Generic{
    optional ResponseBaseA baseResponse =1; 
    optional Der2 requestDer2 = 3;
}
message ResponseBaseA{
    optional int32 responseBaseA = 1;
    optional derResponse1 derivedResponse1 =2;   
    optional derResponse2 derivedResponse2 =3;   
}
message derResponse1{
    optional int32 derResponse1 = 1;
}
message derResponse2{
    optional int32 derResponse2 = 1;
}
message Der1{
    optional int32 d1=1;
}
message Der2{
    optional int32 d2=1;
}
```

Its not deserializing on Java side and getting only this

```
requests {
  baseA: 10
  1000: "\302>\002\b\024"
}
requests {
  baseA: 10
  1001: "\302>\002\b\036"
}
```

I am trying to make my proto file generic because I may have any class(der1/der2/ or more in future) under section requests.

Answer (score 2):

The problem at the moment is that your model specifies both of `der1` and `der2` **for both of** `BaseA<derResponse1>` and `BaseA<derResponse2>`, meaning there are two routes to `der1`/`der2`. In v2, we can avoid this by specifying the inheritance explicitly per closed generic type; so: remove the two `[ProtoInclude(...)]` from `BaseA<T>`, and instead, use:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseA<derResponse1>)].AddSubType(2,typeof(der1));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseA<derResponse2>)].AddSubType(3,typeof(der2));
```

As a side note; it is not required that they use different numbers here, since they are independent. They could both use field `2` is you like; but using different field-numbers is fine too.